# Summing drop down text values

Tags: excel

I've got a sheet with 4 columns that are drop-down lists which describe an arbitrary product. I need a formula that will assign a numerical value to one of the drop down selections, then sum up all of the numerical values for that row. Across the 4 columns there are 9 criteria that can be selected. I've tried:

`=sum((if(b2="x", 1), if(b2="y", 2), if(c2="a", 0.5), if(c2="d", 0.3)` and so forth, but the formula is just too long

Comment: Just sum 4 *VLOOKUP()* formulas.

Comment: i'm not really sure how to structure it, i'm pretty new to LOOKUP() formulas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a table of data to lookup.  You can create it in a new sheet.

```
x | 1
y | 2
a | 0.5
d | 0.3
```

The vlookup takes an input e.g. x and looks at the range of the table of data and returns 1

```
=vlookup(B2,LookupSheet!A1:B5,2,false)
```

=vlookup([what to look for],[range to search],[column in range to return],[type of search, false means exact match]

What Gary's Student is suggesting is

```
    =sum(vlookup(B2,LookupSheet!$A$1:$B$5,2,false),vlookup(C2,LookupSheet!$A$1:$B$5,2,false))
```